# Add page break to text file for printing

Tags: printing, text

How do I add a page break to a text file for printing with `lpr`?

What about if I want to send two files to `lpr` but have each on their own page as in:

```bsh
cat file1 file2 | lpr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also called [paginating text](http://www.dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_17.html#SEC253). You can add a page break character with `pr`:

```
pr -f -h "" -l <num-lines-per-page> text.txt > paginated_text.txt
```

or insert the form feed character directly. In emacs this is done with:

```
C-q C-l
```

Relevant sources:
https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/859-split-text-file-pages.html
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/178755-page-break-file-printing.html

NOTE:
For the record, I couldn't get it to work with `pr`. Help and edits appreciated.